# Synthetic sentence completion

Tags: audio, editing, dialogue

I'm producing a documentary film with several interviews in Adobe Premiere Pro CS5.5 and Adobe Audition CS5.5. In several situations I had to cut before the sentence was completed. Is there any way to make a sentence completion synthetically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your simplest option may just be to find the same words spoken by the same individual in an earlier part of the interview and splice them in.  It will sound much closer to the correct speech than an artificially generated sample.

This issue is the main reason why you don't cut until well after the end of the interview or scene.